# Alterar Exibição da Tabela

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-datatables, table

Existe a possibilidade de eu poder criar um menu, onde eu possa escolher quais campos mostrar na minha tabela?

por exemplo, eu tenho um classe com os seguintes atributos:

**Nome, Cor, DataDeNascimento, Cpf, Rg, Id.**

Então minha tabela iria mostrar justamente todos esses dados.

Só que eu queria poder dar a opção de escolha para o usuário, onde tivesse um menu, com as opções, nas quais ele quer que apareçam, na table.
Como default mostraria todos os campos, mas se ele quisesse ver apenas.
**Nome, Rg**, ou **DataDeNascimento, Cpf**.. Assim sucessivamente.
era só selecionar no menu.
alguém sabe se eu posso fazer isso usando Asp.Net Mvc, Razor..

Edit 1: O problema foi resolvido, usando o dataTable, só que agora eu to querendo imprimir somente as colunas nas quais eu deixei aparecendo.

Meu HTML:

```
<table style="font-size:12px;" id="tableClientes" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Pessoa</th>
                        <th>Cód</th>
                        <th>Cadastro</th>
                        <th>Razão Social</th>
                        @*<th>Nome Fantasia</th>*@
                        <th>C.N.P.J</th>
                        <th>Insc.Estadual</th>
                        <th>-Telefone-</th>
                        <th>Sistemas</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>#</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @if (Model != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TipoPessoa)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)</td>
                                <td style="width:5%">@item.DataCadastro.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</td>
                                <td width="40%">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RazaoSocial)</td>
                                @*<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NomeFantasia)</td>*@
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cnpj)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InscricaoEstadual)</td>
                                <td width="10%">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Celular)</td>
                                <td>
                                    @foreach (var sistema in item.TipoDeSistemas)
                                    {
                                        <p class="sistema" id="topp">@sistema.Descricao</p>
                                    }
                                </td>
                                @if (item.StatusCliente == Smc.Dominio.Model.StatusCliente.Bloqueado || item.StatusCliente == Smc.Dominio.Model.StatusCliente.Cancelado || item.StatusCliente == Smc.Dominio.Model.StatusCliente.Inativo)
                                {
                                    <td style="color:#ff0e0f;text-align:center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StatusCliente)</td>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <td style="color:#00ff21;text-align:center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StatusCliente)</td>
                                }


                                <th style="width:5%; text-align:center">
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("Editar","ClienteEmpresa",new { id=item.Id })" class="load"><i class="fa fa-eye text-success"></i></a>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="11">Nenhum Dado Cadastrado</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>

            </table>
```

Meu script esta dessa maneira:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#tableClientes').DataTable();

        new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons(table, {
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'Imprimir',
                    extend: 'print',
                    header: false,
                    //messageTop: 'Impressão tabela'
                },
                {
                    text: 'Exportar Excel',
                    extend: 'excel'
                },
                {
                    text: 'Salvar PDF',
                    extend: 'pdf',
                    orientation: 'landscape',
                    Header: false
                },
                {
                    text: 'Visibilidade',
                    extend: 'colvis', fixedColumns: {
                        leftColumns: 2
                    }
                },
            ]

        });

        table.buttons(0, null).container().prependTo(
            table.table().container()
        );
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implemente sua table usando o projeto [DataTables](https://datatables.net). Ele possui várias opções e formas de utilização, desde simples tables e complexas com carregamentos com `Json`, recursos de paginação, responsividade, etc... E é amplamente utilizado no mundo.

Segue links do exemplo da funcionalidade que você quer:

- Usando a extensão colvis: https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/styling/colvis.html
- Usando a api: https://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html

Abaixo dos exemplos você poderá ver os códigos utilizados clicando nas abas `Javascript`, `HTML` e `CSS`.

Dê uma olhada na documentação e nos demais exemplos em: https://datatables.net/examples/index

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Perfeito... ja esta usando o dataTable, só que ainda não tinha visto essa opção, ajudou muito. só que agora ta acontecendo o seguinte, no botão Print, ele ta imprimindo tudo, e não só as colunas que estão aparecendo. vou editar a pergunta e colocar o script.

Comment: Altere o botão imprimir incluindo a opção `exportOptions`. Exemplo: `{
                    text: 'Imprimir',
                    extend: 'print',
                    header: false,
                    exportOptions: { columns: ':visible'}
                },`

Comment: Perfeito... Simplesmente Perfeito!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! cara eu nem te conheço, mas já te amo!!!! obrigado!